# Escaping the # character in .env file

Tags: node.js, escaping, dotenv

The secrete API key I want to store in my environment file for my express server is ignoring half of it as it contains a # symbol in the middle. I can't regenerate the key. And do not want it to be left unsequre

Answer (score 26, accepted):

i do not think it's because of the `#` symbol. It is only treated as signaling a comment when encountered as first chartacter in a line...
you can try this yourself. create a `.env` file with the following content:

```
a=#b
c="#d"
#e=f
```

now run `node -e 'console.log(require("dotenv").config())'

this will return:

```
{ parsed: { a: '#b', c: '#d' } }
```

Is there maybe a newline character somewhere?

Comment: Simply putting single quotes around the value did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is definitely the # symbol. I have the same problem. I have a PW and mid-way through it has a #. When I console log the environment variable in my server.js file it cuts the password right before hitting #.

Comment: you are talking about an evironment variable this is about .env Files...

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the `#` symbol and needs single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: I found that I had an issue when I wrapped env var in double quotes, but in single quotes it works fine

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem.
In the `.env` file `#` is working as a breaking point because it is used for comments.
To avoid this and use `#` in your environment variable you can consider your environment variable as a string.

---

For example, if your variable in your `.env` file is `SECRET_CODE= my#code` then change it to `SECRET_CODE= 'my#code'`. This solved the problem in my Express app